# Material-UI injectFirst doesn't work with storybook

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components, storybook

I'm using material-UI with styled-components and according to [documentation](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#injectfirst), in order to override material styles it's required to add this `injectFirst` attribute:

however when trying to use this approach inside storybook environment it does not work as expected and the JSS styles are still injected after styled-components.

**.storybook/config.js:**

```js
import React from 'react'
import {configure, addDecorator} from '@storybook/react'
import { StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/styles'

addDecorator(storyFn => (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
        { storyFn() }
    </StylesProvider>
));
const req = require.context('../packages', true, /.story.js$/);

function loadStories() {
    req.keys().forEach((filename) => req(filename));
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

**DOM:**
styled-components style attribute is still before JSS
[image: styled-components style attribute is still before JSS]

Comment: It's a shame this hasn't worked for you because your code solved my problem getting Material UI to work with my CSS modules.

Answer (score 0):

I was **not** using styled-components, but for MUI + CSS Modules with Storybook v6 the following configuration made it so MUI styles were not overriding our own styles.

*.storybook/preview.js*:

```
import { StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/styles'

export const decorators = [
  (Story) => (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      {Story()}
    </StylesProvider>
  ),
]
```

We had exiting config for `parameters` in that file from another add-on and I just put the above code in there with it no problem. You may also need to import React in there too depending on how you have things setup (we did not).